# Prove there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that the following holds

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be continuous on $(a,b)$ and let $x_1,...,x_n \in (a,b)$. Then, there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that

$$ f(x) = \frac{ f(x_1) + ... + f(x_n) }{n} $$

#### attempt

The natural thing to do is to define $F(x) = nf(x) - f(x_1) - ... - f(x_n)$. Sice $x_i \in (a,b)$ for all $i$, the $f(b) \geq f(x_i)$ for all $i$ so $F(b) > 0$ and similarly $F(a)<0$, thus by IVT there is some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $F(c) = 0$ which gives the result.

However, I feel like Im missing something here. Can I assume $f$ is monotonic?

Comment: You can't, and that's indeed what goes wrong in the argument: You cannot be sure that $f(b) \geq f(x_i)$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $i_{\mathrm{max}}$ be the value of $i$ that maximizes $f(x_i)$, and similarly $i_{\mathrm{min}}$ the value of $i$ that minimizes $f(x_i)$.

What can you then say about $F(x_{i_{\mathrm{max}}})$ and $F(x_{i_{\mathrm{min}}})$?

Comment: Well, then $f(x_{i_{max} }) \geq f(x_i)$ and $\geq f(a), f(b)$, thus $ nf(x_{i_{max}}) > \sum f(x_i)$ thus $F(x_{i_{max}}) > 0$. this correct? but we dont know if $f$ attains max or min in open interval

Comment: The conclusion is correct, but it's not necessarily greater than $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. An example of the opposite is $f(x) = x^2$, $a = -2$, $b = 2$, $n = 2$, $x_1 = -1$, $x_2 = 0$. Note that you do not really need to know anything about $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ though. Similarly, we do not really need to know anything about the potential max/min of $f$; all we care about right now is what happens at  the finitely many points $x_1, \dots, x_n$.